# why does my function only work in the first element of a loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, addeventlistener

I have this tooltip info panels that show up and hide when you click on an icon. I wanted them to close too when you click *anywhere* else but the icon, as seems natural.

I've done something that works, but ONLY for the first tooltip of the page. I got several and when trying to loop the behavior it just won't do it and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Here's what I have

```js
// Dropdown to show or hide tooltip
var dropdownButton = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown__btn");

for (i = 0; i < dropdownButton.length; i++) {
  // Action when clicking
  dropdownButton[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.classList.contains("is-hidden")) {
      panel.classList.remove("is-hidden");
    } else {
      panel.classList.add("is-hidden");
    }
  });
  // Closes when clicked anywhere else
  // Only works with the first one, though it logs the message for each one
  window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {;
    if (!dropdownButton[i].contains(e.target)) {
      console.log("you're NOT clicking the btn");
      dropdownButton[i].nextElementSibling.classList.add("is-hidden");
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
}
```

```css
.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="dropdown__btn">x</p>
<div class="dropdown__panel is-hidden">
  <p>Renew automatically on every expiration date.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: dropdownButton.length ? dropDown button is not an array

Comment: @KaanCetinkaya It isn't an array, but its a HTMLCollection, which does have a `.length` property

Comment: Also, altering elements in an HTMLCollection has the possibility of changing the length since it is a live reference to the DOM. Try `document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown__btn")`

Comment: Change `for (i = 0;` to be `for (let i = 0;`. With your version `i` is a global variable which is referenced throughout all your event-listener functions.

Comment: @NickParsons Yes, that is working now. Thanks a million!